# Integration of Java and Python 3.x Code in One Project

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, cross-language

I am writing my project using python 3.x. I've come to a stage where I needed to write some code in Java.Is there anyway to integrate Python 3.x and Java?
I am acknowledged about Jython.But it does not support Python 3.x as i know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Integrate what exactly? What are you trying to do? Do you need to call one from the other, exchange data, ...? And why do you need to mix languages?

Comment: This is a duplicate question you can see in this post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880736/integration-of-java-and-python-code-in-one-eclipse-project

Comment: My project needs to use cross languages.I need to write some part of my project in java and some part in python 3. @UnholySheep

Comment: That question was about the integration of python 2 and java. Answer was to use jython.But Jython do not support Python 3. First understand the question then comment! bttX @bttX

Comment: You still didn't explain what exactly your two programs are supposed to do with each other. Without that information it's impossible to give you a clear answer (though this question is most likely too broad anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two projects that use JNI to connect the standard python interpreter into a JVM, both projects support python 3.

- [JPy](https://github.com/bcdev/jpy)
- [Jep](https://github.com/mrj0/jep/)

I would recommend starting with JPy since you currently have python and it allows you to [call java from python](http://jpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#running-java-from-python).